# Why do git ls-remote and git ls-files fail with some relative paths?

Tags: linux, bash, git, git-ls-files, git-ls-remote

Suppose I have a git repo at `~/dev/company/products/company-common`. From several other filesystem location I try to execute `ls-files` or `ls-remote` on that repo. All work, except for the last one. What could be a reason the last one doesn't work?

(N.B. I have a 2-line bash prompt):

```
user@machine:products (~/dev/company/products)
$ git ls-remote company-common HEAD 
f25b342b384de1b82cb67b6f530303b4fac37ff0    HEAD

user@machine:products (~/dev/company/products)
$ git ls-remote ../products/company-common HEAD
f25b342b384de1b82cb67b6f530303b4fac37ff0    HEAD

user@machine:products (~/dev/company/products)
$ git ls-remote ../../company/products/company-common HEAD
f25b342b384de1b82cb67b6f530303b4fac37ff0    HEAD

user@machine:products (~/dev/company/products)
$ cd gui

user@machine:gui [master] (~/dev/company/products/gui)
$ git ls-remote ../company-common HEAD
f25b342b384de1b82cb67b6f530303b4fac37ff0    HEAD

user@machine:gui [master] (~/dev/company/products/gui)
$ cd dummy/

user@machine:dummy-application [master] (~/dev/company/products/gui/dummy)
$ git ls-remote ../../company-common HEAD
fatal: '../../company-common' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

None of the directories involved is a symlink. I've only shown one line of output from each command (except for the last one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interesting thing is that `git ls-remote` works at all here.

The first argument you pass to `git ls-remote` should be a URL (`https://host/...`, `ssh://git@github.com/...`, and so on) or the name of a remote (typically `origin`).  However, Git accepts local file system paths in place of `file://...` URLs.

When Git does that last trick, it seems to do it somewhat weirdly and inconsistently.  In my experiments I got somewhat different behavior, but it was still weird.

Aside from academic curiosity and/or possible internal bugs, you should just stop using `git ls-remote` here and use `git rev-parse` directly.  If you want to get a revision hash ID from the current repository, just run `git rev-parse`:

```
git rev-parse HEAD
```

for instance.  If you want to get one from some other Git repository in file system location X, use:

```
git -C X rev-parse HEAD
```

for instance.  This behaves well—unlike the odd results you and I are seeing for `git ls-remote` here, the `-C` argument makes Git internally `chdir` for the duration of the rev-parse—and runs faster and is simpler and easier to deal with.  It works for `git ls-files` and all other Git commands too, since it is implemented in the `git` front end.

Comment: Thanks, I was unaware ls-remote working here (and it worked as expected for years!) was just luck as we are notusing it as intended. Using `rev-parse -C` is a good suggestion, better than the alternative we chose.

Comment: Careful: the `-C` argument must come *between* the `git` command and the sub-command (`rev-parse`).